# installing Magento via github

Tags: magento2

Been following a tutorial but it installs dev version of Magento2. How can I install the stable version 2.1.x ?

cd /var/ww/html/

git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git

cd magento2

composer install

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to the 2.1 branch after cloning the repository.

```
git checkout 2.1
```

Comment: How do you 'check out' is this a switch ? Could you show complete code of line please?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout to the correct branch first. `git checkout 2.1`

**Edit:** you can also checkout to a specific tag. `git tags` will reveal what's available.

You may also want to look at installing from composer directly. I prefer it that way myself but you do need to sign up to Magento and get your authentication keys (which are like a username and password to download Magento 2) this way so it can be a bit of a pain to get going the first time.

You use a command like this: `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition YOUR_FOLDER_NAME`

Comment: Does it also not use tags?  Could this OP not use a tag such as '2.1.*"?

Comment: @camdixon I was just wondering the same thing. I am on a mobile looking at the repo now but there's no mention of tags. Running `git tags` will show if there are.

Comment: they are there actually.  2.1.1 and 2.1.2 exist as tags

Comment: @camdixon does github.com hide tags  on its mobile site?

Comment: Looks like it yes,  I could not find on my phone when I just searched.

Comment: @camdixon Handy :/